# Are these Bansuri Notes all on the Low Octave (to me they are on Low and Middle)

Tags: notation, indian-classical, octave, bansuri, saptak

As a newbie I am trying to play these notes of `O RE PIYA`

http://sargamnote.blogspot.com/

To my ear, all the notes belong in the Low and Middle Octave of this beginner Bansuri Fingering Chart (as circled in Pink)

[image]

However the way it is written makes me think they are in two different octaves

I believe

DHA SA RE RE, 
MA GA SA DHA, 
DHA SA RE RE
DHA PA MA GA MA, 
SA RE SA

should be re-written as as

**'DHA** SA RE RE, 
MA GA SA **'DHA**, 
**'DHA** SA RE RE
**'DHA 'PA** MA GA MA, 
SA RE SA

In other words, `'PA` and `'DHA` are in the Lower Octave while `SA` to `MA` are in the Middle Octave.

Is my thinking correct? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partly correct.

It is right that the song is in the *mandara* (lower) and *madhya* (middle) *sthayis* (octaves), whereas the notation 
incorrectly places all the *swaras* (notes) in the middle octave.

However, not every *dhaivatam* and *panchamam* in the given notation should be played in the lower octave. Only those that correspond to the lines "O Re Piya Haye" and "Tanabana Tanabana" should be played in the lower octave. The rest are in the middle octave.

Observe that the portion `Dha Pa Ma Ga Ma, Sa Re Sa,` corresponds to "Udne Laga Kyon" which is not in the lower octave because it's clearly not starting at the same pitch as "O Re Piya" (which is in the lower octave).

---

I should also add that the notation given in the link is not entirely accurate.

- The section "Bunti Hawaa" is incorrectly notated. It is notated as `Ni Re Pa
  Ga` but it should be correctly notated as `Sa 'Pa 'Ni 'Dha`
- The correct length of time for which each note should be played is also sometimes not accurately given. For instance, "Udne Laga Kyon" is notated as `Dha Pa Ma Ga Ma ,` but this should instead be `Dha , Pa , Ma Ga , Ma , ,`.
- More importantly, they have shifted the *shadjam* down by one note. You can observe this by comparing the pitch of the *shadjam* in the section where Rahat sings *swaras* from [2:50 onwards](https://youtu.be/5awZ9sOTA54?t=170) in the linked video. Pause at the point where he repeats the *shadjam* and then compare that with the pitch of "ya" in "O Re Piya". They are the same, yet the given notation claims that "ya" is to be played at the *rishabham*.
- Thus, every note that is given in the link should actually be changed to one lower, that is `Re` should be changed to `Sa`, `Dha` should be changed to `Pa`, etc.

The last mistake changes the *ragam* of the song, even if it happens that the song can be notated in this manner without encountering any contradictions.

Comment: Wow, very thorough and comprehensive! Who knew, because Rahat is singing swaras, one can tell  that notes should be changed to one lower. How fascinating!

Comment: And I have to figure out instrumental notes between `O Re Piya Haye, O Re Piya` and `Tanabana Tanabana Bunti Hawaa` to eventually play on Bansuri

Comment: @Marium The harmonium portion of the instrumental is the same as "Tanabana Tanabana". There is a small flute portion following that, and that part is a bit difficult to notate, though...

Comment: Ah, ok then .... Will practice known notes, then delve into harmonium part.